# Pyqt - Can not get any output from QProcess

Tags: pyqt, stdout, qprocess

I have read a lot of similiar problems on SO and also anywhere on internet but i could not find solution for this.

i have the following command which i want to run:

```
c:\\lscc\\Programmer\\3.8_x64\\bin\\nt64\\pgrcmd.exe -infile test.xcf
```

From CMD window i have standard output like this:

> Lattice Programmer Diamond (64-bit) 3.8.0.115.3 Command Line Argument
>   check - OK Loading Programmer Device Database... Done. Writing log
>   file to /programmer.log Opening XCF file... Done. Programming XCF
>   Contents... Connected to Lattice Cable Server. Failed.

I want to run it in my app via QProcess but i cant not find the way how to get same output.
I have following code, the command is performed and i cant get any output:

```
process = QProcess()
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
process.start("c:\\lscc\\Programmer\\3.8_x64\\bin\\nt64\\pgrcmd.exe -infile test.xcf")
process.waitForFinished()

> process.readAllStandardError() = b" # empty
> process.readAllStandardOutput() = b" # empty
> process.exitCode() = -9
```

Only thing where is something usefeull is in errorString:

```
> process.errorString() = "Unknown error"
```

Comment: try with: `process.start("c:\\lscc\\Programmer\\3.8_x64\\bin\\nt64\\pgrcmd.exe",  ["-infile" "test.xcf"])`

Comment: @eyllanesc My god, really? It works! I didnt even try it because Qt doc says both methods should do same job. The question is why they dont.

Comment: QProcess needs to differentiate between the program and its arguments.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the following method:

> **void QProcess::start(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, QIODevice::OpenMode mode = ReadWrite)**

and clearly QProcess needs to differentiate between both so you must separate it:

```
process.start("c:\\lscc\\Programmer\\3.8_x64\\bin\\nt64\\pgrcmd.exe", ["-infile" "test.xcf"])
```

Comment: As i mentioned in previous comment why this works and this: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprocess.html#start-2 not? It says you can pass all in one string separeted by spaces as i had in my question.